# C++ Event Handler

Tags: c++, events, event-handling

I am pretty new to C++ and I recently encountered the following problem: hwo do I handle events in C++? I have worked with XNA and this stuff there is easy (or at least it is easy to do what I need): you can just write myObject.MyObjectEvent+=MyObjectEventHandler(functionToStartOnEvent)
does this have an equivalent in C++?

Comment: [function pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) or handler objects

Comment: That completely depends on the platform. WinAPI? Qt? ...

Comment: Well, I am using GLFW to initialize my window, don't know if that helps you.